# Django allauth No Reverse Match

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-allauth

Django allauth fails when using a custom user model with the email as the primary key, I learnt about this when I tried to test the password change functionality.

```
Reverse for 'account_reset_password_from_key' with keyword arguments '{'uidb36': 'mgodhrawala402@gmail.com', 'key': 'bbz25w-9c6941d5cb69a49883f15bc8e076f504'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$']
```

I don't mind going into the code to fix this issue, since my application is still under development, I can still change authentication incase anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this problem would be adding a sequence integer pk and just updating your email field to index unique because as you see the regex path doesn't accept email format for `uidb36`, it only accepts `0-9A-Za-z`.

If you must use email as pk you can add another path to your urls to accept your email pattern:

```
from allauth.account import views


path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
re_path(
    r"^accounts/password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>.+)-(?P<key>.+)/$",
    views.password_reset_from_key,
    name="account_reset_password_from_key_accept_email",
),
```